# Powering PCB with USB and adapter

Tags: power, pcb, circuit-design

I have working systems and I want to make a PCB for it. My system needs 24V (for stepper and relay) and 9V for RFID and 5V (for ADC reads) and 3.3 V for ethernet. I am using 2 switch regulator 24->12, 12->5 and I am using 2 linear voltage regulator 12->9 and 5-> 3.3V. I have two question about it.

My system needs USB for code upload. So I need to use USB cable at least one time. Then, I will use these regulators for powering. I have schematic here:

What I want to ask is; when I try to upload code to microcontroller, I won't plugged 24V adepter. I will upload code through to USB cable so will V_USB cause something? When I use micro USB, V_USB will equal 5V. So 5V output power will cause something for R-78E5-0.5  (top of the right)?

I am asking because I made small experiment. I used ld1337. I connected 3.3V to OUTPUT and GND to GND. I measured 2.64V on INPUT.

[image]

Comment: mis-spelling sorry

Comment: There's an [edit] link below your question ...

Comment: The black negative schematic cannot be seen. When converted into a normal positive image then the contrast is too low to be seen. Why not post it as a positive high contrast image in the first place?

Comment: @Audioguru I added new photo. Sorry for that. I added diode between 12V's output and V_USB by that, 12V's output don't powered by V_USB right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to upload code to microcontroller, I won't plugged 24V adepter.

You will forget and it will happen. It always happens.

> I will upload code through to USB cable so will V_USB cause something ?

You need a diode between V_USB and internal +5V to make sure that your board DOES NOT send +5V into the PC's USB port. Under some conditions that can blow the chip behind the PC's port. A schottky diode rated for 500mA is a good option.

This means, when your board is powered from USB only, your +5V will only be about +4.5V, but that's not a problem because from what I understand from the question, the board needs +24V to actually run.

> When I use micro USB, V_USB will equal 5V. So 5V output power will cause something for R-78E5-0.5 (top of the right)?

It's a switching regulator, so the internal MOSFET has a diode between output and input. So, if the output is powered at 4.5V from the USB port through the diode, this will raise +12V to about 4V, and the same will happen with the other DC-DC, so the +24V line will get about 3.5V.

I have the exact same thing happening on a board, with the same Recom DC-DCs. It's not a problem at all, the DC-DCs don't care. However, if there is a load on your +12V or +24V that decides to draw a lot of current, that may exceed what the USB port can deliver and then it won't work. Or some of the chips may not work at all with such a low power supply voltage.

Your LDO is different from the DC-DCs, if it doesn't have a MOSFET with a body diode as a pass device, then it should not be powered from its output. NCP1117 datasheet, page 10 top left, says you shouldn't worry because it has an internal protection diode.

Another problem if you use USB to program your micro while the board is unpowered is that the micro will then boot and send some IO signals to the other chips that are unpowered. This could power them from their inputs through the protection diodes, and this can cause damage.

So you could, for example, add a reset chip to keep the micro in reset if +24V is not at the correct voltage. Or you could do it in software, check +24V with the ADC, and if it is not satisfactory, print something on the serial port and wait, instead of sending active IO to the unpowered chips. Hardware reset chip is more reliable, of course.

Comment: thank you, you give me really good solutions and specifications.  You said output is powered at 4.5V from the USB port through the diode, this will raise +12V to about 4V and you said it is not problem. Can I add there a diode. I mean can I add diode to +12V(R-78E5)'s output. If I do that,  R-78E5's (12V) input won't  raise +12V to about 4V right? Again thank you, you answered all  question that in my mind.

Comment: Oh yes you can add a diode before R78E5's input (I assume you meant input in the above comment). The diode should be before the cap, not between the cap and the DC-DC.

Comment: sorry for late comment, I upload new photo of my schematic. I added this [diode](https://ozdisan.com/power-semiconductors/diodes-diode-modules-and-rectifiers/schottky-diodes/DFLS130LQ-7) . It is 30V , 1A probably. Is it enough right? I don't want to power 12V's output with V_USB so I added diode between them. Should I add capacitor for them ?

Comment: Diode is alright, but I can't see on the schematic if it's in the right direction due to the symbol. No need for capacitor there, but note that 7809 won't work with capacitor in GND pin.

Comment: Thank you, I made wrong schematic. That  470 uF caps should be connected to output pin.

Comment: Also NCP1117 is not stable with just a ceramic capacitor on the output, it needs an electrolytic cap for ESR, for example 100µF. If you want a LDO that works with 10µF ceramic, try [this one](https://ozdisan.com/Product/Detail/588458/LDL1117S33R)

Comment: OK! but look at the capacitor on the GND pin, in the new schematic you posted, it's on the output, not on GND...

Comment: Sorry , sorry I just see. Again thank you for your helps and thank you for that link. Have a nice day.